# redstone item splitter drops all items into 1 hopper

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to replicate this [design](https://youtu.be/hoARdQOW--4?t=264).

So far, I am making a copy of it, block to block, in my survival and creative worlds. They both lead to 1 result - all items are getting sent to 1 channel.

In his video I can see how first set of comparators flashes one by one, but in my case they seem to be off all the time;

1. Does it still work or is it some outdated model?
2. What is a potential issue with the way I do it?

[image]

[image: with only solid blocks]

Comment: I see for example a piston and an observer in the video, but not in your images. Of course you need to build the entire thing, with all the blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the comparators are off that means there is no item in the droppers.
You need to put a single item in one of the droppers to activate this circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the left side of your screenshot; you are using glass. Notice how the redstone signal can’t travel down steps made of glass.

You can remedy this issue by replacing them with solid blocks.

Comment: that's not the problem, it was the same with solid blocks i just put glass for this screenshots

Comment: @VladimirZaguzin Thanks for your comment. I'll still leave this answer up to inform others, but I'll try to find another possible issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the single item in the droppers ?

It's this item moving back and forth between the hoppers that lock/unlock the hoppers.

Comment: Hasn't this info been already stated in the previous post? Please do not repeat info.